# Cómo ejecutar codigo para varias celdas de Excel a la vez

Tags: excel, vba

Hola ojala me puedan ayudar, lo que pasa es que ya tengo este codigo funcionando pero solo se ejecuta cada vez que seleccionas la celda:

```
Sub buscar()
Dim score1 As Double, score2 As Double, result As Integer
score1 = ActiveCell.Value
If score1 >= 0# And score1 <= 0.1 Then
result = 1
End If

If score1 >= 0.1 And score1 <= 0.2 Then
result = 2
End If

If score1 >= 0.2 And score1 <= 0.3 Then
result = 3
End If

....etc.... son varios if
End Sub
```

lo que me gustaria saber es como ejecutar este mismo codigo para varias celdas a la vez ya que el codigo se tiene que ejecutar y hacer la comparacion en 1000 registros y ps es cansado ir haciendolo uno por uno, espero haberme explicado y gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En el código que de la pregunta se indica ActiveCell.Value, lo cual te devuelve el valor de la celda activa, pero lo que deberías hacer es escoger una forma de obtener múltiples celdas. Para ello lee [Bucles en un rango de celdas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/office/ff840655.aspx).

Nótese que puedes usar `For...Next` o `For Each...Next` para aplicar la misma operación a varias celdas y que puedes usar `Cells` o `CurrentRegion`.

Por otro lado, veo que estas usando múltiples IF. Considera en lugar de hacerlo así, usar [Select Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/office/gg278665.aspx) ya que resulta mas conveniente en estos casos.

Otra obsevación más, es acerca de los intervalos que has indicado en el código, se translapan, lo cual no es una buena práctica porque bajo ciertas condiciones podría causar problemas, por ejemplo, Si score1 es 0.2 el valor de `result` primero será 2 y luego será 3.

Answer (score 0):

Por cómo van las comparaciones, parecería que es sólo truncar celda * 10.

Lo más fácil, si tienes que aplicar eso sobre un rango, es no usar una macro, sino escribir una función, aplicarla a la primera celda y luego copiarla, siguiendo la forma del rango.

Si no, puedes usar iteraciones sobreun rango, como
For i = n To 1 Step -1
        buscar(aRange.Cells(1, i) )

y hacer buscar paramétrica respecto a un argumento con la celda, en vez de usar ActiveCell.